# Why in Obj-c is not possible to leave self to reference the current Class?

Tags: objective-c, self

Why in Obj-c is not possible to leave self to reference the current Class? is there some special reason why you can't do that? or is possible to do that somehow anyway?

I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind using self in an object. If I type `[self runMethod];` then I'm refering to method in the class that the line itself is in, so what is the point of using the self keyword? why not just allow me to put `[runMethod];` ?

So I'm guessing there's some fundamental reason why the self keyword is needed?

Comment: Bear in mind that being concise is not the goal of objective-c (a language known for verbosity).  Self is needed, not necessarily because the message couldn't be resolved automatically, but because it allows you to easily see the intended target of a message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `self` in `[self doStuff]` indicates the target object that you are calling the method on. It is perfectly sensible (and, in fact, very common) to call methods on a target other than your`self`:

```
NSObject *obj = ...
[obj doStuff];
```

`self` just happens to be one such target.

From the perspective of language design: It is conceivable that `[doStuff]` could be made a shorthand for `[self doStuff]`, but it would be a pretty weird special case (which might lead to some syntactic ambiguities!), and it's not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to duskwuff's answer, which is good, I want to note that this is incorrect:

> If I type `[self runMethod];` then I'm refering to method in the class that the line itself is in, so what is the point of using the self keyword?

When you message `self`, you may invoke a method in a *subclass*, not necessarily the class whose implementation did the messaging. Not directly relevant to your question, but an important distinction to understand.